# How to get environment configuration values in an ActionMailer class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I want to place an image in emails to let me know if a person has opened the email. So the image will simply be a route in my rails app to a specific controller to handle that logic:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/invitations/43/open.png" />
```

Problem is, `http://www.example.com` works in production, but we have different development and test environments. Is there a way to use an environment configuration value in the `/config/environments` Ruby files inside an ActionMailer template?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the action_mailer.default_url_options if you set it in your config files (config/environnments/).

If you set in production.rb and developpment.rb like so

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'www.example.com' }
```

You can call it anywhere using

```
Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host]
```